# Is it possible for someone to steal my source code for a ASP.NET web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, webforms, html

I have a simple question in which I couldn't find an exact answer to, that question being:
If I created an ASP.NET webpage, is it possible for someone to steal my C# source code?
And if so, how can I protect my webpage's source code from being stolen/dumped/reverse engineered?

Please if you do know anything about this, as many replies as possible would be greatly appreciated! Thank you guys so very much, even if you just give me an idea on this topic! :)

Comment: It depends who you think this someone could be, and the way you deploy your changes. A simple user of your website can't have access to any of your cs files, this is blocked by default. Someone having access to your server could have access to it, and if you don't want that you'll need to compile everything into one or more DLL files. But those dll files could be reverse-engineered. It all depends how far you want to secure the whole stuff ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a corporate user or a regular user?
Someone accessing your website from a web browser, like a standard user can not access your aspx/cs server side code. However if you are talking about a corporate user, if they browse to your web server and have access to your inetpub\wwwroot directory (or wherever your source resides) they have full read or maybe even write access. It all depends on the type of user, and the user security system in place for your domain, whether the person trying to get in is part of your domain and has proper privileges on your server. Also some client side scripts are exposed to user's as well.

So as far as server side scripts, users not part of your domain, and stringent security settings on your web server, are all factors contributing. But I think you mean in the context of a user just trying to access code from the web browser without any additional permissions. Which in this case would be no.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer but your C# code will be better protected if you use a Web Application rather than a Web Site. Your C# code will be compiled so even with an FTP access (or a direct access to the production server, if you suspect an inside threat), one won't be able to download your .cs files. Of course, one can download .dll and reverse engineer but that's something.

Read more about Web Apps vs Web Sites here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge there is not a way for someone to steal your asp code unless you allow them to see the file itself. If you view source you will see that the majority of the asp code has been changed either to html or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

> > If I created an ASP.NET webpage, is it possible for someone to steal my C# source code?

Yes it is, there just to many ways how this can happen, vulnerability in the hosting environment, IIS exploit, your code allowing to download things etc. Just *accept* that your libraries (I assume they are compiled by the time you deploy) will be downloaded and protect them accordingly.

> > How can I protect my webpage's source code from being stolen/dumped/reverse engineered?

You cannot have an ultimate protection, but you may make life complicated for the person trying to reverse engineer it. Probably the most  effective solution is to use code obfuscation. You may also want to read more general documentation on this topic, such as [Design Guidelines for Secure Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648647.aspx).

Comment: I'd disagree with the "Just assume" bit. While there will always be ways to get the source, you're skipping over quite a few layers of (relatively effective) security there - and it's all about layers :)

Comment: Well, the problem is that hackers (governments) are always one step ahead. It's hard to fight something that has not been yet discovered. I agree it's all about the layers, hence included the link, but once it's in the web, you can no longer rely on stuff not being copied. Even simple fact of upload would very likely to end up somewhere in the middle of nowhere in the US (if you follow the NSA disclosure).